# How to change connection for a session in hiberante?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

Is it possible to change/set the connection for an Hibernate Session?
For example, if the dbconnection fails/is closed while using a session, we need to set a new connection for the same session.
Thanks

Comment: adding more detail on the code you have implemented on what you have done so far would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Session.reconnect(Connection)`. Works in Hibernate 3.5.4